# Laptop not starting after installing Arch Linux

Tags: linux, arch-linux, linux-kernel

Good day lads.
Today I have ran into the most unique problem ever. I installed Arch Linux with no issues, rebooted once and it brought me into the ArchISO so i rebooted again; It was stuck on stopping the job for the network adapter for 10 mins so I held down the Power Button for a forced shutdown. I wanted to start my laptop but all it there was, was a very silent sound of something trying to start. My Power LED just blinks with a 1 second delay and it does that until I shutdown my Laptop.

HDD doesn’t start.
Fans wont start.
Screen wont even turn on.
Can’t open my CD/ROM.

I suppose that the CMOS Battery is dead due to forcefully shutting off my laptop a lot this evening. Yes the Laptop Battery fully charged.

[Video of me trying to start it](https://streamable.com/5md69r)

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the CMOS, if it doesn't work, take it to repair. And just throw away your network adapter and buy a normal USB WiFi adapter! (a joke, but true)